# Using CMapStringToString

Tags: c++, mfc

I have need of a simple hash table in my project and from the documentation it seems like **CMapStringToString** is exactly what I want.  However, I've found that simply adding a new field to my class is sufficient to throw an error message, even if I'm not otherwise accessing it.

```
 ... other class members
 CMapStringToString myMap;
```

Just doing this gives me this error:

```
... 
error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in 
class 'CObject'
```

Nowhere is anything referencing **myMap** as yet.

The file & line number for the error is "afxcoll.h" at line 1503, which is the closing brace of the CMapStringToString class definition.

Does anybody know what the problem is here?  Is there sample code for this class anywhere?

---

Someone had earlier posted an answer suggesting the problem was that the copy constructor was private and suggested creating my own copy constructor for the class with the map.  This does not work, and whomever posted it actually deleted their own answer (after I'd read it but before I'd responded).

---

I ended up creating a class derived from **CMapStringToString** and wrote a copy constructor for it. This wasn't quite the same thing as the earlier suggestion and it worked.  Thanks to all for your suggestions. They may not have been exactly right but they at least steered me in the right direction.

Comment: Since CMapStringToString works just fine (and I use the term loosely - the MFC maps & arrays are just bad in my opinion) the problem is obviously not there. Can you show you some more context from your code? A few lines before the CMapStringToString line and the *actual* error messages generated would help tremendously.

Comment: The line shown above was the only reference anywhere. The immediately preceding and following lines were just declarations of int variables.  This *is* the actual error message. It was cut and paste from the the output window... All I left out was the reference to "afxcoll.h" which was mentioned underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your class doesn't have a copy constructor and you're trying to copy an instance somewhere? Most of the time this wouldn't yield an error, but since the underlying type of the `CMapStringToString` class is `Object` it might be needed.

Comment: Not sure that's not right, but the error occurs without the map being referenced anywhere.

Comment: I'd skip CMapStringToString altogether and use std::map<CString, CString> instead.

Comment: I tried using std::map and while it compiled OK, I got all sorts of weird linker errors referring to 'metadata'.  I've since gotten around the original problem, however, by creating a derived class and adding a copy constructor.